# unable to compile opencv 3.4.4 from source

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-18.04

Running ubuntu with 5.3 kernel.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:307: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8259: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
```

Also:

ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you share the link help you to install opencv?

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/